# Child process updates shared mmap memory but no change in parent process

Tags: c++, c, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

I am trying to save a struct in shared memory created by mmap and as shown in the code below:

**The problem** is, child process appears to be updating the struct in shared memory but when the parent process tries to read it, it throws an error.

```
struct name{
    char * name;
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    struct name * s_memory = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct name), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

    pid_t p = fork();

    if(p == 0) {
        printf("In Child Process\n");

        s_memory->name = strdup("test name");

        printf("Child Process name: %s \n", s_memory->name); // Print - test name ok!!

        puts("exit child process");
        exit(1);

    } else {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Parent Process name: %s \n", s_memory->name); // SEGV !! - Not Updated
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

1. What is the problem here?
2. Why does removing the `strdup` and doing something like this works:

   ```
        s_memory->name = "test name" // with strdup throws SEGV but works without strdup. why?
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you store only the *pointer* to the string in shared memory, the string itself is allocated by `strdup` via `malloc`, which is in the program heap, i.e. outside the shared memory region.

You should store the string itself in shared memory, for example like this:

```
struct name {
    char name[1024];
};


   // . . .

   strncpy(s_memory.name, "test name", sizeof(s_memory.name));
```

Comment: What if I want to store  another `struct name` inside the original `struct name` . How would that work?

Comment: @lynxx You can store what you want, but pointers out into the process' memory are not available to the other process. Well,  you can read the value of a pointer (which is in shared memory), but not dereference it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry my bad, I want clear enough. I want multiple processes to share dynamic data such as a struct. So, if I cant store pointers, how can I store dynamic data in shared memory?

Comment: You'll need to allocate enough space and possibly create a custom allocator/deleter. Also be sure to lock the area you are reading from/writing to. Are you sure that you don't want to use threads instead?

Comment: Shared memory is given to you as a contiguous blob of memory. You can store a structure of any complexity inside of it. But you need to manage it yourself. For example, at the beginning you can store an `int size`, followed by that many instances of `struct name`. Of course you also need a mutex or a semaphore to synchronize updates, `sleep` is not enough. Also try googling "shared memory manager in C++".